# Cannot access disk partition (created by gparted) from windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, gparted, ntfs

I Cannot access disk partition (created by gparted) from windows 10.

### There are two disks in my laptop:

- Disk 1 (Windows 10  | ntfs)
- Disk 2 (Ubuntu 16.10 | ext4, swap, **ntfs**)

I wanted to have that ntfs partition (highlighted above) accessible from both Windows and Ubuntu (have shared partition with files)

### Partitions were created in the following way:

1. Formatted Disk 2 using windows standard tool
2. Boot live USB (Try Ubuntu)
3. Used gparted to delete all partitions created by windows on Disk 2 (about 7 of them including HP win recovery and a few of the windows partitions all are 2 MB - 800 MB in size)
4. Used gparted to create 3 partitions on that Disk 2. Here's an image:
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUGvZ.png)

### After that, Ubuntu has been installed in the following way:

1. Chose ext4 mount point as: /
2. I didn't choose any mount point for ntfs on that Disk 2
3. Installed Ubuntu to ext4.

### Result

I can write/read files on that ntfs partition on that Disk 2 from Ubuntu, but when I start up windows 10 I can see the Disk 2 as an empty disk (444 GB of 444 GB available) and when I open it I get a message saying that I can't access the disk.

### What is the solution?

Do I have to just reinstall it again but do not delete all the windows partitions created by formatting, this time? Will it help windows to see the ntfs partition then?

Or Do I have to simply mount it using "disks" ubuntu utility and let it mount on startup, will that help?

### P.S.

I saw a similar question here:
[Windows XP can't access NTFS partitions created with gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41393/windows-xp-cant-access-ntfs-partitions-created-with-gparted)

But when I do:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
t
0x07
```

I get: Changed type of partition 'Linux filesystem' to 'PowerPC PReP boot'.

I'm not sure if that's a good idea to write these changes. So this solution doesn't really helped me.

Comment: What happens if you do a `chkdsk /f d:`, changing the "d" to the correct drive letter, if different?

Comment: Before running `chkdsk` (which might take a while), you could try reformatting the drive from Windows.

Comment: @wjandrea chkdsk runs pretty quickly. OP **did** initialize the drive from Windows.

Comment: @heynnema OP created the partition with GParted. See steps 3 and 4 in the question.

Comment: @wjandrea ah! OP started with Windows init, and then later recreated everything in gparted. OP should just delete the NTFS partition and recreate it in Windows using the Disk Management app.

Comment: @heynnema when I do `chkdsk /f d:` I get **Access Denied as you do not have sufficient privileges. You have to invoke this utility running in elevated mode.**

Comment: You have to start an `administrative command prompt` window to perform the chkdsk.

Comment: @heynnema thanks, I managed to make it work by creating NTFS partition (gparted in live cd mode) at the beginning (first sectors) of a disk and then re-installed Ubuntu so that it wouldn't take the first sectors of the disk..

Comment: @wjandrea thank you guys, I managed to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add this as a comment but I don't have the reputation.

Windows has a bad reputation with FAT and NTFS partitions created after or behind a non-Windows partition. I've found a comment from  that explains it well (https://superuser.com/a/613864):

> "The only other possibility that springs to mind is that this is a
>   Windows bug -- namely, that it can't read a primary partition that
>   comes after an extended partition. If so, the obvious (but awkward)
>   solution is to delete the NTFS partition, use a Linux emergency disc
>   and GParted to move your Linux partitions to the end of the disk, and
>   to create a fresh primary NTFS partition that comes before the
>   extended partition."

I hope it helps.

Comment: You are right. It solved the problem. I added the upd. Thanks!